# Estimating sum of two gaussians using a single gaussian

Tags: calculus, analysis, statistics

### The problem

I have a sum of gaussians:

$$
\Sigma(x) = p_1 e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x-u_1}{s_1}\right)^2} + p_2 e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x-u_2}{s_2}\right)^2}
$$

which I'd like to approximate with a single gaussian:

$$
A(x) = (p_1+p2)e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x-u_3}{s_3}\right)^2}
$$

I'd like to find values of $u_3, s_3$ (that are independent of $x$) that minimize the integrated squared error

$$
E(u_3, s_3)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{(\Sigma(x)-A(x))^2}dx
$$

### My attempt

This can be broken down into three separate integrals:

$$
E(u_3, s_3) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\Sigma^2(x)}dx-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\Sigma(x)A(x)}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{A^2(x)dx}
$$

Which I can simplify to:

$$
E(u_3, s_3) = K-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\Sigma(x)A(x)}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{A^2(x)dx}
$$

As the $K$ part is independent of $u_3$ and $s_3$

One useful property on product of gaussian distributions:

$$
g(x,u_a,s_a)g(x,u_b,s_b) = \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(u_a - u_b)^2}{s_a^2 + s_b^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi(s_a^2+s_b^2)}}g(x,u_c,s_c)
$$

Where $$u_c = \dfrac{u_a s_b^2 + u_b s_a^2}{s_b^2 + s_a^2}$$ and $$ s_c = \dfrac{s_a s_b}{\sqrt{s_b^2+s_a^2}} $$

If $u_1 = u_2$ and $s_1 = s_2$, then:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{A^2(x)dx} = \dfrac{(p_1+p_2)^2}{2 s_3 \sqrt{\pi}}
$$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\Sigma(x)A(x)}dx=p_1 (p_1+p_2) \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(u_1 - u_3)^2}{s_1^2 + s_3^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi(s_1^2+s_3^2)}}+p_2 (p_1+p_2)\dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(u_2 - u_3)^2}{s_2^2 + s_3^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi(s_2^2+s_3^2)}}
$$

One heuristic is to set $u_3 = p_1u_1+p_2u_2$, and solve for just $s_3$ (resulting in 1D roots)

To find the minima of $E$, I'd then need to find partial derivatives of the above nastiness with respect to $s_3$, and then find the subsequent root that leads to a minima. Intuitively, a root has to exist, (since guessing either too low or too big of a standard deviation is bad). But there may be many roots.

### Issues

I'd need some way to tell when replacing 2 gaussians with a single one is actually sensible. Just finding a minimum in the error function doesn't mean that it's sensible.

I can try a completely new approach using estimated moments as well. But I haven't looked much into this.

Answer (score 0):

no complete answer, but first, to get properly normalized distributions, I would rewrite:

$$
\Sigma(x) = \frac{p}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}} + \frac{1-p}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}
$$

$$
A(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_3^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_3)^2}{2\sigma_3^2}}
$$

I think your goal is to solve the two equations:

$$
\frac{\partial E[\mu_3, \sigma_3]}{\partial\mu_3} = 0, \frac{\partial E[\mu_3, \sigma_3]}{\partial\sigma_3} = 0
$$

I have not tried to perform calculation... To solve that problem I would personally run a least-square method.

On the other hand, if you do not want to perform a numerical computation, I think easiest is really to solve two equations equalling the mean and variance:

$$
E[x] = \mu_3 = p \cdot \mu_1 + (1 - p) \cdot \mu_2,
$$

$$
E[x^2] - E[x]^2 = \sigma_3^2 = p \cdot (\sigma_1^2 + \mu_1^2) + (1 - p) \cdot (\sigma_2^2 + \mu_2^2) - (p \cdot \mu_1 + (1 - p) \cdot \mu_2)^2
$$

Given the very rough approximation you are doing to approximate the sum of two gaussians by another gaussian, it is probably enough.

HTH